# Verifying toasts using Appium , and get server reaction to button clicks

Tags: selenium, appium

i'm new to android automation testing and i recently started to work with Appium.

I use it for android native app automation.

I have 2 question -

1. is there a way to verify toasts?
   the latest posts i saw which referred to this issue are from the mid of 2014
   and i wanted to know if there's something new in this subject before i will find another tool to run my tests with (as i understand selendroid can verify toasts).
2. is there a way to catch the http request which my app sends to the server when i'm pressing a button, during the automatic test?
   something like a listener which works in the backround and wait for clicks?

tnx

Comment: Have you tried using Selenium AndroidDriver? Its easy to setup. Selenium does not support displaying the Http requests / responses.

Answer (score 0):

To verify toast messages you can use one of image recognition libraries. For ruby I use [RTesseract](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract) together with image processor [RMgick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)

Idea is simple:

1. make toast message to appear
2. take few screenshots
3. iterate over taken screenshots and look for text

You may play with image processing, to increase recognition quality.

Here you can find code snippet which I use in my framework: [link](https://gist.github.com/brbrr/ac09fd5ec4fc326ca688)